# What exactly makes a reed relay different from a regular relay?

Tags: relay, terminology

I understand that a reed relay is a reed switch with a coil added, but the internals of a reed switch:

[image]
([source](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/magnetic-sensors-and-reed-switches/reed-switches/mism-7.aspx))

sure do look a lot like the contact portion of a regular relay:

[image]
([source](https://instrumentationtools.com/basic-concepts-of-the-safety-relay/))

What exactly is it that makes a reed relay a distinct type of relay, rather than just one of several ways of making a relay? Why are reed relays easier to make with high-voltage ratings? (I am assuming they're easier to make, anyway, because high-voltage reed relays cost a lot less than high-voltage regular relays.)

Comment: Sparks between contacts caused by ionized gas. Reed relay's contacts in vacuum, no or little amount of gas. Higher voltage should be applied for ionization.

Comment: @user263983 You can buy evacuated relays (many kilovacs are, for instance) and they're not called reed relays, though. They also cost much more than reed relays.

Comment: On a quick search [A Complete Guide to Reed Switches](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery/ideas-and-advice/reed-switches-guide) says read relays are housed in a hermetically sealed glass bubble or envelope and (a) often filled with an inert gas like nitrogen to help prevent particle build-up causing performance issues over time (b) The hermetically sealed nature of reed switches means they won’t corrode and pose no risk from sparking on actuation.

Comment: Not sure about this... but geometry? Every switch i remember (not many) where the two magnetic arms are inside an air-core solenoid, were called Reed. Non-reed ones seem to have the actuator outside the solenoid (with or without magnetic core).

Answer (score 15):

Hermetic sealing is very important because it reduces contact oxidation considerably and means that they will reliably switch tiny voltages and currents. Regular relays (and switches) usually state a minimum wetting (or whetting) current to guarantee reliable operation at low voltages and currents but, reed relays always seem to be in a better ball-park of performance in this respect.

The lack of irregular pressure changes and an inert gas in the internal cavity means that they can have considerably higher open-circuit voltage ratings for the same clearance between contacts. This won't apply to all of them of course but, it's a reasonably expectation in general.

As Chester alludes to in his comment under the question, they can be used to switch currents and voltages in hazardous (ignitable) gas areas and I used one many years ago for that same reason. You have to pick a type that does conform with the regulations of course.

<sub>A reed switch (as opposed to a relay) maybe should be mentioned; they form the basis of many door/window open detection systems requiring virtually no power (other than a magnet and mechanical movement) to operate them).</sub>

Comment: If this is the main difference, I'm having a hard time understanding the distinction between a reed relay and a hermetically sealed kilovac; the latter is more expensive by far for the same voltage rating.

Comment: @Hearth I'd have to know a part number for the item you refer to as kilovac

Comment: Let's say a Sensata [DAT72415F](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sensata-cynergy3/DAT72415F/752018) compared to a TE [K81C335](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-aerospace-defense-and-marine/K81C335/3071319). The latter costs about five times as much and is listed as a standard relay, while the former is listed as a reed relay. They're both rated for the same switching voltage, although the kilovac is rated for somewhat higher current.

Comment: I don't see the term "kilovac" appearing in the former. In the latter, it appears to be some kind of trade name. I don't think we're taking about reed relays now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time wording things right now. The former is not a kilovac, it's a reed relay with similar ratings to one. The latter is a kilovac, which is TE's brand of hermetically-sealed conventional relays, and about the only ones (other than Sensata's competing gigavac series) that go to such high voltages. The price differential between the Sensata reed relay and the kilovac was what inspired me to ask this question in the first place, because I don't see what makes the construction that different.

Comment: Without an internal view of both devices I have no idea @Hearth

Answer (score 10):

**IF** I have not missed the point of the question then the other answers and comments seem to have.

A reed relay is fundamentally different in operating principle than most standard relay types.

In a reed relay the contacts, or contact arms contain ferromagnetic material "blocks". An external magnetic field is applied to the immediate area  causing the two contact-attached blocks to attract and the contacts to be driven closed.(Operation may be more complex than that, but that suffices for now).  The applied field is usually applied from the outside of a hermetically sealed envelope. The envelope is non ferromagnetic and is an insulator. The key factor is the operation of the contact structure by an applied magnetic field. Insulating housing and inert gas atmosphere are bonuses.

Most "normal" relays operate by utilising magnetic attraction of an armature, and a mechanical coupling that drives one or more contacts. The mechanical connection makes insulation and inert atmosphere far harder.

The relay example that you used has a part missing, for reasons unknown.
The green added line represents an actuating bar that allows the armature to drive the central contact. The overall complexity relative to a reed is evident.
[image]

A reed *could* be added where the contacts are and the coil moved closer - but still with an isolating insulated wall.

While relay construction varies immensely, the differences seen here compared to a reed are typical.

---

> As a follow-on question, what about this mechanism makes conventional relays more resistant to contact welding? Because I know welding is typically an issue for reed relays, which is why they don't tend to come with current ratings as high as standard relays. –

A mechanical relay can be designed to have as much "oomph" (technical term:-) ) as desired. In the above image the centre contact arm provides the restoring force, and can be as strong as desired - with the armature force counteracting. Some relays have positive contact motion in both directions with external springs as required.

A reed has only restoring forces within its envelope. These are contact arm provided (although some have internal permanent magnet biasing). The field is more remote from the magnetic material and the activation material constrained by available size.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I suppose the magnetic field over by the contacts would be too weak to actuate the mechanism, so it's mechanically linked to a solenoid? As a follow-on question, what about this mechanism makes conventional relays more resistant to contact welding? Because I know welding is typically an issue for reed relays, which is why they don't tend to come with current ratings as high as standard relays.

Comment: @Hearth  off the cuff with no checking:  A mechanical relay can be designed to have as much "oomph" (technical term:-) ) as desired. In the above image the centre contact arm provides the restoring force, and can be as strong as desired - with the armature force counteracting. some relays have positive contact motion in both directions with external springs as required. || A reed has only restoring forces within its envelope. These are contact arm provided (although some have internal permanent magnet biasing).  The field is more remote from the magnetic material and the activation  ...

Comment: ... material constrained by available size. || I designed a "miniature roomlight" torch with a PM activated reed switch - 100% waterproof. I chose highest survival-g-rated acceptably priced reed. In practice it survived torch-body g's far above its rated value. Mounting only incidentally accommodated extra g-shock protection. This doesn't address contact bounce under g forces (which didn't matter in this application) but indicated very acceptable ruggedness. || The smaller lights [**here**](https://bit.ly/SL2MINIAFRICA). Roll down. Larger ones have conventional switches. Both "indistructable".

Comment: This is the only correct answer - different construction. You might want to add that "actuator bar" type relays often have multiple NO as well as NC contacts that switch at the same time with guaranteed break-before-make. Reed relays, while elegant and small, are limited to one NO contact.

Comment: @RainerP. Thanks. Other answers focused on electrical rather than construction differences. The OP wanted the latter. People have got clever with reeds and made them NC (by adding a permanent magnet internal bias) and multi pole in same envelope. BUT, as you say, the large majority are single pole NO - and I've not seen any of the others in practice.  || I've used 100,000 ++ reed switches (not relays) with PM operation. A very successful application. [**here**](https://bit.ly/SL2MINIAFRICA) roll down. The smaller lights - almost unseen in some photos!

Answer (score 3):

Reed relays have a few advantages, such as being hermetically sealed- generally at a price that does not suggest a military level budget (as with welded hermetic relays) They're also relatively fast, more like 0.5 to 1ms max for general-purpose types compared to the 5ms-10ms of relays. Switching voltage/current ratings are relatively modest for the low-cost type. Another downside is the tendency to stick 'on' when they fail, which almost never happens with regular relays unless they are abused and welded.

High voltage vacuum reed relays are a kind of niche market where they have a purpose.

You may find that telecom style signal relays are more reliable for low voltage signal switching. They are sealed but not hermetic.

For higher power switching, being sealed (hermetically or otherwise) can reduce the lifetime, and we often deliberately break the seal after PCB washing.

Comment: What exactly makes high voltage vacuum reed relays so much cheaper than high voltage vacuum conventional relays? A 5 kV rated reed relay from Sensata is *way* cheaper than a 5 kV rated kilovac from TE.

Comment: @Hearth current rating? Seems like the kilovacs are tens to hundreds of amps, and the reed relays are milliamps to single-digit amps.

Comment: @Hearth [KILOVAC High-Voltage DC Contactors](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=9-1773446-7_kilovac&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN#:~:text=For%2035%20years%2C%20KILOVAC%20contactors,in%20aerospace%20and%20military%20applications.) shows ratings up to up to 1000 A at 1000 VDC. How does than compare to the Sensata reed relay?

Comment: @ChesterGillon I'm thinking of the lower current ones like the K81 series, which only go up to 5 A. A little more than the 2 A Sensatas that I've used, but they cost 5 times as much, and I don't understand what makes the technology so different that there's such a large price differential.

Comment: @Hearth The TE K81C335 datasheet lists Shock (peak 30 G's) and Vibration in it's specification. The Sensata DAT72415F datasheet doesn't. Perhaps the price difference is that the TE is designed for a harsher environment (the Aerospace, Defense and Marine market).

Comment: @ChesterGillon I suppose that would make sense. I don't understand why it doesn't count as a reed relay, though, under the definitions people have given here. Starting to feel like I asked an XY question, actually! I wanted to know why kilovacs are so much more expensive than high-voltage reed relays, and maybe fixated on the wrong thing. Can't change the question now though--it has two good answers that I'd hate to invalidate. Maybe I'll ask another one later.

Comment: You put photos of very ordinary mass-market relays/reed switches in there. A question with exotic vacuum relays showing the inner workings would be interesting, if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

From a comment under the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694656/101063):

> The price differential between the Sensata reed relay and the kilovac was what inspired me to ask this question in the first place, because I don't see what makes the construction that different. – Hearth

From the TE [K81C335](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=SD-K81C&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English&DocFormat=pdf) datasheet:
[image]

Whereas the  Sensata [DAT72415F](https://www.cynergy3.com/sites/default/files/cynergy3-d-v3.pdf) datasheet doesn't mention shock and vibration.

Perhaps the price difference is that the TE is designed for a harsher environment (the Aerospace, Defense and Marine markets), even when the electrical specifications are compatible.